# My dogs would have already barked, if it really HAD BEEN A BURGLAR

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

I know a bit how to use 3rd conditional, but not quite.

Situation: You suddenly heard sound from the lower ground of your house, which made you nervous about a burglar might be sneaking into your house. You almost forgot that you have got not-so-friendly dogs that bark when they see strangers. And you said:

> Nah, my dogs would have already barked, if it really **had been a burglar.**

Is this correctly constructed? Because I've included the "be verb" specifically "been" in the sentence.

P.S.: The sentence above is a hypothetical thinking about a past event.

Comment: It's correctly constructed. More formal alternate: "... had it really been a burglar." Side note: False positives abound; dogs bark whether it's a burglar or the wind or just for the hell of it.

Comment: "Had it really been a burglar" -I don't quite catch this suggestion, my register is casual, not formal. Also, it's like I were to form a question tag, which is not what I intend to do here. Thx for this, by the way.

Comment: @John Arvin - nothing to do with question tags. When talking about something that might have happened in the past, but did not, we can invert the subject and the verb - e.g. "if X  had been Y then..." can become (more formally) "had X been Y then... " see [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page67.shtml)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, right, anyway, is my sentence correct? I really doubt the part "had been a burglar" you know...

Comment: There are two possible verb tenses in the if clause: *had been a burglar* is correct if you consider the noise to be in the past. *were a burglar* is better if you consider the noise to be in the present.

Comment: Two of the existing answers were made based on the original question in which you used **already**. Without that word existing, the answers no longer make sense. I have put the word back in place. If you want, you can remove the word from your question again—but please add some kind of commentary saying that it had been there originally. (In other words, don't invalidate existing answers by editing your question.)

Comment: The sentence is fine. "if it really had been a burglar" is exactly the same as "had it really been a burglar". The second option is fine but everyone uses the first, which is 100% grammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your scenario, you **heard** a sound.  That sound happened in the past.  Now you're worried. You can calm yourself down with either of these thoughts:

> Had it (that is, had *that sound*) really been a burglar, the dogs would have barked.
>
> Had it (that is, had *that sound*) really been a burglar, the dogs would be barking.

That is to say, the dogs would have barked (their barking would also have happened in the past). Or the dogs might have started to bark upon hearing the sound and they might still be barking.

If you want to bring that sound into the present, you would use the present perfect: You have heard a sound, and you're wondering if it is a burglar.

> If that sound I've heard is really a burglar, the dogs would be barking.

Comment: If my sentence is already fine, then I'm contented. Anyhow, this is the best answer, if I were to say my sentence in the present.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where the time frame of the main clause is not the same time frame as the time frame of the conditional clause. When this happens, you need to use a mixed conditional:

> My dogs would have already barked, if it really were a burglar.

This construction puts the dogs' barking in the past, and the hypothetical burglar in the present.

You can mix clauses from hypothetical conditions (2nd and 3rd) with each other, and clauses from real conditionals (0th and 1st) with each other in this way, but you shouldn't mix clauses from real and hypothetical conditionals.

Comment: Peter, I don't agree that the time frames are not the same. The "if" clause is suppositional (hypothetical), indicating otherwise. There is no need to use a mixed conditional.

Comment: @Robusto: What you're worried about is whether there is a burglar downstairs *right now* when you're hearing the noise, not whether there was a burglar downstairs two minutes ago when the dogs didn't bark. Maybe you don't actually *need* to use a mixed conditional, but it seems more natural to me, especially if you use the word *already*.

Comment: @all: please see my updated construction, leaving out the "already", to indicate that my time frame all played out (main and relative clause) IN THE PAST.

Comment: @PeterShor: That's just where we differ, I suppose. Either is *possible*, but my way seems more natural to me.

Comment: @Robusto: I think I side with Peter on this particular "fine point". As he says, the issue is whether there ***is*** a burglar downstairs right now - but the standard tense coupling *My dogs **will** have already barked, if it really **is** a burglar* simply doesn't work unless we assume both "speakers" are actually deaf (and conversing in sign language! :). In *that* hypothetical scenario, the "posited future + present" works fine. As with *The neighbours will have already dialled 911 if it really is a burglar, so we can just sit tight and wait for the police to arrive.*

Comment: Why are you bringing up mixed conditionals?Is that relevant to the OP's utterance? It was: "Nah, my dogs would have already barked, if it really had been a burglar." [I say right now to you ten minutes after the incident.]

Comment: @Lambie: I don't see how that makes sense with the word *already* in there. If the sentence had been *Nah, my dogs would have barked, if it really had been a burglar*, you wouldn't have needed a mixed conditional. But *already* sets the time frame as the present.

Comment: @Peter Shor The italicized sentence in your post is exactly the OP's sentence. You make my point except for the already. Now, I give you: I would have already answered this question yesterday, if I had been home. [speaking to you right now.] I have no objection to the already for this utterance in a present time.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the "already".

Had it really been a burglar, my dogs would have barked.

I have some suggestions for you: You suddenly hear a sound coming from the ground floor of your house (or from downstairs), which makes you nervous about a burglar trying to sneak into your house.

Comment: Kindly break it down why I should leave out the "already". The remaing sentences after the first one are a bit off, my sentence happened in the past. Anyway, thx.

Comment: I just think the sentence sounds better without it, but the others think it is fine, so I'm probably wrong.